# strict warning: Non-static method

Tags: php, drupal

I am getting an errors on www.westerford.co.za on all the pages. These errors are causing the content to be hidden.

Some of the errors include...

```
strict warning: Non-static method view::load() should not be called statically in /path/sites/all/modules/views/views.module on line 906.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_validate() should be compatible with views_handler::options_validate($form, &$form_state) in /path/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc on line 607.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter::options_submit() should be compatible with views_handler::options_submit($form, &$form_state) in /path/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_filter.inc on line 607.
strict warning: Declaration of views_handler_filter_term_node_tid::value_validate() should be compatible with views_handler_filter::value_validate($form, &$form_state) in /path/sites/all/modules/views/modules/taxonomy/views_handler_filter_term_node_tid.inc on line 302.
strict warning: Declaration of views_plugin_row::options_validate() should be compatible with views_plugin::options_validate(&$form, &$form_state) in /path/sites/all/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_row.inc on line 134.
```

Please go to the site and see all the errors. **What might be causing them?**

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I solve "Non-static method xxx:xxx() should not be called statically in PHP 5.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768576/how-can-i-solve-non-static-method-xxxxxx-should-not-be-called-statically-in)

Comment: Views doesn't support >=PHP5.4 yet. It works, but you'll get a ton of these types of notices

Comment: @Clive, how do I make this site work again? It worked last week.

Comment: They're just warnings they shouldn't be taking the site down. Try turning off error reporting at admin/config/development/logging. If that fails, get hold of your error log and look for a fatal error. If you find that and need help deciphering it, I'd recommend asking on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/), you'll probably get a quicker response

Comment: Strike that, it's not a fatal error as the site still loads. I can't think why a few notices would stop panels from rendering though. I'm taking a stab that you're using Drupal 6 (not 7)? I'm pretty sure your server must be running php5 strict mode (which Views for Drupal 6 doesn't support, see [this bug report](https://drupal.org/node/465332)). If that's been recently enabled it would explain the change in fortunes

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the issue was fixed but answering anyway for the record.
The problem was that the PHP version was different than the one on which the views module was developed on back then.
Every time you should check if there is any new version of Views / CTools and if there is a patch on the modules issue page that would fix your problem. You're never the only one having such problems and it's highly possible that the issue is already solved.

BTW: disabling warnings doesn't make the problem go away :). **An advanced developer always checks the error log - watchdog and handles those issues.**