# Non-static method XXX should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

Recently handed over a school portal to me to manage, it works fine on server but it fails to work on my local machine, the login page loads perfect but when trying to login I got:

```
ERROR - 2020-05-29 23:51:37 --> Severity: 8192  --> Non-static method menu::getPermDetail() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context C:\xampp\htdocs\ug\application\models\menu.php 113
ERROR - 2020-05-29 23:51:37 --> Severity: 8192  --> Non-static method menu::getPermDetail() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context C:\xampp\htdocs\ug\application\models\menu.php 113
ERROR - 2020-05-29 23:51:37 --> Severity: 8192  --> Non-static method role::haveAccess() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context C:\xampp\htdocs\ug\application\modules_core\admin\views\header.php 74
ERROR - 2020-05-29 23:51:37 --> Severity: 8192  --> Non-static method menu::menuIcon() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context C:\xampp\htdocs\ug\application\modules_core\admin\views\header.php 146
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "Non-static method xxx:xxx() should not be called statically in PHP 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768576/how-can-i-solve-non-static-method-xxxxxx-should-not-be-called-statically-in)

Comment: Enabling php short_tag in php.ini file solve the problem. thanks