# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC

Tags: php

I am getting this error in this PHP code on line 3, what could be wrong? This code has been taken from php manual [user notes by frank at interactinet dot com](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#103757)

```
<?php

public function myMethod()
{
return 'test';
}

public function myOtherMethod()
{
return null;
}

if($val = $this->myMethod())
{
 // $val might be 1 instead of the expected 'test'
}

if( ($val = $this->myMethod()) )
{
// now $val should be 'test'
}

// or to check for false
if( !($val = $this->myMethod()) )
{
// this will not run since $val = 'test' and equates to true
}

// this is an easy way to assign default value only if a value is not returned:

if( !($val = $this->myOtherMethod()) )
{
$val = 'default'
}

?>
```

Comment: Looks like this is supposed to be **part of a class definition**. This won't run as is.

Comment: in addition, the code is showcasing *bad programming*, something you should not do. Why would you want to use the code?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `public` keyword is used only when declaring a class method.

Since you're declaring a simple function and not a class you need to remove `public` from your code.

Comment: what's the difference between a public function in a class and a function out in the open?

Comment: You can also hit this error from not closing a bracket & that runs into the next function... It will throw this error on that function. 
That's what I did. 
Don't be like me.

Comment: @Tanner_Gram I did what you did so I checked every single braces, and it works

Answer (score 3):

You can remove public keyword from your functions, because, you have to  define a **class** in order to declare **public, private or protected function**