# Non-static method ..... should not be called statically

Tags: php, static, non-static

I have recently done an update to PHP 5.4, and I get an error about static and non-static code.

This is the error:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method VTimer::get() 
should not be called statically in /home/jaco/public_html/include/function_smarty.php on line 371
```

This is the line 371:

```
$timer  = VTimer::get($options['magic']);
```

I hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

That means it should be called like:

`$timer  = (new VTimer)->get($options['magic']);`

The difference between `static` and `non-static` is that the first one doesn't need instantiation so you can call the `classname` then append `::` to it and call the method immediately.
Like so:

```
ClassName::method();
```

and if the method is not static you need to initialize it like so:

```
$var = new ClassName();
$var->method();
```

However, in PHP >=5.4 you can use this syntax instead as a shorthand:

```
(new ClassName)->method();
```

Comment: Or perhaps he should change the method to be static (since this is an existing codebase now being run in an upgraded PHP environment).

Comment: @mamdouh 
You are great, the error is gone.
Thank you for your help.
Have a nice evening.


sincerely,

Jaco

Comment: @user2938848 - you are welcome. I hope you mark the answer as accepted, as it works with you :)

Comment: By faster calling : (new ClassName)->method(); you mean shorthand. Right?

Comment: Im sure that syntax is the intention.

Answer (score 23):

You can also change the method to be static like so:

```
class Handler {
    public static function helloWorld() {
        echo "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The most elegant way would be :

```
(new ClassName)->method();
```

You can also convert your function to `static function call() {}`, but that depends on your function and what you're doing with it.

If you need to instantiate a class then avoid doing so, treat static functions like constants, they can not have objects and require predefined variables.

Answer (score 3):

```
public function functionName($variable)
```

Change to

```
public static function functionName($variable)
```