# How to get the Variation ID in a Woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm trying to get in a plugin I'm writing the variation ID of products. Here's what I wrote:

```
class mass {

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes',array($this,'thfo_mass'));


    }
public function thfo_mass()
    {
        $id = WC_Product_Variation::get_variation_id();
        //$lenght = get_post_meta($id,'_length');
        //$dimensions = wc_get_dimension(24750, 'cm');
        var_dump($id);
    }
```

I only get an error:

> Deprecated: Non-static method WC_Product_Variation::get_variation_id() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in path/to/plugins/thfo-raw-material-for-woocommerce/class/mass.php on line 19

> Notice: Undefined property: mass::$variation_id in path/to/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variation.php on line 257
> int(0)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693946/non-static-method-should-not-be-called-statically

Answer (score 6):

try this.

```
 <?php 
    $product_obj = new WC_Product_Factory();
    $product = $product_obj->get_product($product);                             
    if ($product->product_type == 'variable'):
        $children   = $product->get_children( $args = '', $output = OBJECT ); 
        foreach ($children as $key=>$value) {
            $product_variatons = new WC_Product_Variation($value);
            if ( $product_variatons->exists() && $product_variatons->variation_is_visible() ) {
                $variations[$value] = $product_variatons->get_variation_attributes();
            }
        }
   endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_variation_id` is not a static method at all.

You need to create an instance/object of `WC_Product_Variation`, then you can use it.

Like ---

```
$variable_product = new WC_Product_Variation($value);
$variable_product->get_variation_id();
```

Comment: what is the `$value` ?

Comment: variation value

Comment: what is variation value?

Comment: example, you have added a variation called color and values are red, green, blue etc

Answer (score 2):

Please check this result is here: [How to get Woocommerce Variation ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646939/how-to-get-woocommerce-variation-id)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
    'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'asc',
    'post_parent'   => get_the_ID() // get parent post-ID
);
$variations = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

    // get variation ID
    $variation_ID = $variation->ID;

    // get variations meta
    $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_ID );

    // get variation featured image
    $variation_image = $product_variation->get_image();

    // get variation price
    $variation_price = $product_variation->get_price_html();

    get_post_meta( $variation_ID , '_text_field_date_expire', true );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've managed to figure out so far:

Firstly, to get the colour:

```
$colour = isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( 'pa_colour' ) ] ) ? wc_clean( stripslashes( urldecode( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( 'pa_colour' ) ] ) ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( 'pa_colour' );
```

Then in my foreach loop that is generating the checkboxes:

```
$variation_id = searchForVariants($colour, $size, $available_variations);
$product_shipping_classes = get_the_terms( $variation_id, 'product_shipping_class' );
$product_shipping_class_name = ( $product_shipping_classes && ! is_wp_error( $product_shipping_classes ) ) ? current( $product_shipping_classes )->name : '';
```

Then you can use `current( $product_shipping_classes )->term_id` or `current( $product_shipping_classes )->slug` or `current( $product_shipping_classes )->name`.

The searchForVariants function is in my `functions.php` file:

```
function searchForVariants($colour, $size, $array) {

    foreach ($array as $key => $sub_array) {

        if ($sub_array['attributes']['attribute_pa_colour'] === $colour && $sub_array['attributes']['attribute_pa_size'] === $size) {
           return $sub_array['variation_id'];
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The `$available_variations` array is already in the storefront theme in the  `variable.php` but I am using a child theme so copied the template file to make these changes.