# How to get Woocommerce Variation ID?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I've already had this code on functions.php

This code is to add a new field on each product variation to have datetime input field, so variations would automatically expired when the current date is past the input date.

```
// Add Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );

// Save Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

//Create New fields for Variations
function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    // Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_text_field_date_expire[' . $variation->ID . ']',
            'class'       => '_text_field_date_expire',
            'type'        => 'datetime-local',  
            'label'       => __( 'Date of Expiration', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'placeholder' => '',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __( 'Expiration of Each Product Variation', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_text_field_date_expire', true )
        )
    );
}


//Save New Fields for Variation
function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    // Text Field
    $text_field = $_POST['_text_field_date_expire'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field_date_expire', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
}
```

This is to add a new field on each variation of Wocommerce.

What I am trying to do is to get each "_text_field_date_expire" meta so I could delete expired variation for each of the products..

How do I get each woocommerce variation ID on functions.php so I could add a rule that it will expire when it is already past the current date right now?

```
var_dump(get_post_meta( $variation_id , '_text_field_date_expire', true ));
```

This code is the one that I will use to get the datetime field, but not sure how I could get each `$variation_id` field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
    'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'asc',
    'post_parent'   => get_the_ID() // get parent post-ID
);
$variations = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

    // get variation ID
    $variation_ID = $variation->ID;

    // get variations meta
    $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_ID );

    // get variation featured image
    $variation_image = $product_variation->get_image();

    // get variation price
    $variation_price = $product_variation->get_price_html();

    get_post_meta( $variation_ID , '_text_field_date_expire', true );

}
```

Hope this will helps you. For more information:

- [How To Get Product Variations & Meta – WooCommerce](http://www.sutanaryan.com/2015/11/how-to-get-product-variations-meta-woocommerce/)
- [How to get the Variation ID in a Woocommerce product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916601/how-to-get-the-variation-id-in-a-woocommerce-product)

Comment: This is right! Thanks! Problem now is how I could delete the variation using this code..

Comment: update_post_meta( $variation_ID , '_text_field_date_expire', ""); use this to make your variation filed value null. Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 5):

In WooCommerce 3+, it's **`$variation->get_id()`** from `$variation` function argument, which is an instance of the [`WC_Product_Variation`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html).

The method `get_id()` is inherited from [`WC_Data`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#methods) class.

So in your code it should be instead:

```
'id' => '_text_field_date_expire[' . $variation->get_id() . ']',
```

> Since WooCommerce 3, All `WC_Product` properties can't be accessed directly. Instead, you need to use the available methods.

---

Also in your hooked function `save_variation_settings_fields()` you are declaring 2 arguments, so **there is one missing**. It should be:

```
//Save New Fields for Variation// Save Variation Settings
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

function save_variation_settings_fields( $variation_id, $i ) {
    // Text Field
    $text_field = $_POST['_text_field_date_expire'][ $variation_id ];
    if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_text_field_date_expire', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
    }
}
```

See [the source code for **`woocommerce_save_product_variation`** action hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data.html#383)