# How do i resolve Deprecated: Non-static method Session::get() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\ooplr\classes\token.php on line 13

Tags: plugins, php, database, session

This code generates hashed password

```
class Token {
    public static function generate()
    {
        return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token)
    {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

        if (Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

But then I can't debug this program , please what's wrong it. thanks in ADVANCE

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684454/error-message-strict-standards-non-static-method-should-not-be-called-staticall#answer-4684514 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693946/non-static-method-should-not-be-called-statically

Comment: I see no question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `Session` class `get` function declaration.

From:

`function get()`

to:

`public static function get()`