# Using :: for non static methods?

Tags: php

In the PHP manual it states that the [Scope Resolution Operator(::)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) has the following purpose

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in
>   simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to
>   static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.

Now I just came across a tutorial that was using the double colon like this:

```
class A {
  public function nice(){
    echo "hi";
  }
}

$A = new A;
A::nice();
```

and the output is actually

> hi

But why does this not throw an error? The function `nice` is not a static method, nor is one overriding the method. Is it bad practice to use the double colon like that?

Comment: That's because you haven't enabled error reporting ([demo](https://3v4l.org/5DVZI)). There's a lot of junk learning material I'm afraid.

Comment: Reaction depends also on PHP Version in PHP70 its this : `Deprecated: Non-static method foo::bar() should not be called statically in `

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I actually found that in the book PHP Master from sitepoint.

Answer (score 3):

It works for backwards compatibility with PHP 4, if your error reporting is on you will get warning:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method A::nice() should not be called statically

**EDIT** Actually you will get error in recent versions, not warning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684454/error-message-strict-standards-non-static-method-should-not-be-called-staticall

Answer (score 1):

It actually returns Deprecation notice and it's a bad practice:

`PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method A::nice() should not be called statically`

It does not throw an error, because it's not referencing `$this`, so this method could be static anyway.

If you would try to reference `$this`, you will get following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context`