# Accessing One to many relation giving non static methode should not be accessed stitically error Laravel5.3

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3, one-to-many

I have two model Products and Photo. These models are followings

> Photo Model

```
public function Product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
```

> Product Model

```
public function Photo(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
    }
```

I need to get all the photos of a product catagory. For this i have tried this

```
$Photo =  Products::Photo()->where(['catagory' => $request->catagory])->get();
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> ErrorException in IndexController.php line 49: Non-static method
>   App\Product::Photo() should not be called statically

How to solve it? And what is the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message Strict standards: Non-static method should not be called statically in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684454/error-message-strict-standards-non-static-method-should-not-be-called-staticall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the something like following to access the Photos of a category of the product.

```
$product = Products::where(['catagory' => $request->catagory])->with('Photo')->get();
$photo = $product->Photo;
var_dump($photo);
```

See `Photo();` method of the `Product` class is not the method that you can access directly via the class name (Static way of accessing method of a class).

You are try to call the method of a class just like as we do with static method for example

```
ClassName::Method_name()
```

But your Photo method is not static neither the class.

Update: For relation, its **better to put** (Optional) the related foreign key which establishes the relationship

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Photo','your_foreign_key_for_this_relation');
```

Comment: It says 'Mthod Photo does not exist'

Comment: sorry my bad, i have updated the code see and match your class name and method name , and put `$product->Photo` instead of `$product->Photo()`

Comment: Here is my code and this gives me undefiened property exception 
$product = Products::where(['catagory' => $request->catagory])->get();
        $photo = $product->Photo;
        return json_encode($photo);

Comment: there no such index called Photo in $product object. and i have tried that too.

Comment: `$product = Products::where(['catagory' => $request->catagory])->with('Photo')->get();` and `$product->Photo`

Comment: Yes yes man that worked :). Thanks for your time and effort. Could you please update the answer :)